# scrollView.dragging == true after scrollViewDidEndDragging?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

It seems that in the UIScrollViewDelegate function

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

sometimes, scrollView.dragging is true even after

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)willDecelerate
```

is called.

Is that somehow expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `willDecelerate` of [`scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDragging%3awillDecelerate%3a) is `YES`, then yes, that's expected. You get `scrollViewDidEndDragging` when the user lets go of the drag, but [`dragging`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW2) doesn't change until the visual scrolling/decelerating is done. Thus, when you let go of a drag, you may see `scrollViewDidEndDragging` followed by some `scrollViewDidScroll` (and `dragging` still `YES`).

Alternatively, you can check out [`tracking`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW3), which turns to `NO` as soon as the user lets go (even though the scroll view may still be scrolling).

Comment: `isTracking` is also at true for me in `scrollViewDidEndDragging`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `UICollectionView.isDragging` and even `UICollectionView.isTracking` are not reliable at all. You must store a property to keep track of the dragging state like this :

```
class YourScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var isDragging = false    

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        isDragging = true
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        isDragging = false
    }
}
```